# Encountered this error while implementing NTT cpp code: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc' what(): std::bad_alloc

Tags: c++, cryptography, post-quantum-cryptography, ntt

I recently started implementing post-quantum crypto and needed to implement the polynomial multiplication for which number theoretic transform (ntt) is used to reduce its time of computation and this code below is one of the approach(not the most optimal but optimal compared to naive convolution implementation) and this is the code i've used in implementing multiplication of two polynomials using number theoretic transform (ntt) for post-quantum kyber crypto. I encountered this error while implementing the below code:
`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc' what():  std::bad_alloc`

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int MODULUS = 17;
int GEN = 13;
int pm(int base, int exp, int modulus) {
    int result = 1;
    base %= modulus;
    while (exp > 0) {
        if (exp % 2 == 1) {
            result = (result * base) % modulus;
        }
        exp >>= 1;
        base = (base * base) % modulus;
    }
    return result;
}
std::vector<int> cooley_tukey_ntt(const std::vector<int>& a, int gen = GEN, int modulus = MODULUS) {
    if (a.size() == 1) {
        return a;
    }

    std::vector<int> omegas(a.size());
    omegas[0] = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < a.size(); ++i) {
        omegas[i] = (omegas[i - 1] * gen) % modulus;
    }

    std::vector<int> even, odd;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i += 2) {
        even.push_back(a[i]);
        odd.push_back(a[i + 1]);
    }

    std::vector<int> even_ntt = cooley_tukey_ntt(even, pm(gen, 2, modulus), modulus);
    std::vector<int> odd_ntt = cooley_tukey_ntt(odd, pm(gen, 2, modulus), modulus);

    std::vector<int> out(a.size());
    for (int k = 0; k < a.size() / 2; ++k) {
        int p = even_ntt[k];
        int q = (omegas[k] * odd_ntt[k]) % modulus;
        out[k] = (p + q) % modulus;
        out[k + a.size() / 2] = (p - q + modulus) % modulus;
    }

    return out;
}
std::vector<int> cooley_tukey_intt(const std::vector<int>& a, int gen = GEN, int modulus = MODULUS) {
    if (a.size() == 1) {
        return a;
    }

    std::vector<int> omegas(a.size());
    omegas[0] = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < a.size(); ++i) {
        omegas[i] = (omegas[i - 1] * pm(gen, modulus - 2, modulus)) % modulus;
    }

    std::vector<int> even, odd;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i += 2) {
        even.push_back(a[i]);
        odd.push_back(a[i + 1]);
    }

    std::vector<int> even_ntt = cooley_tukey_intt(even, pm(gen, 2, modulus), modulus);
    std::vector<int> odd_ntt = cooley_tukey_intt(odd, pm(gen, 2, modulus), modulus);

    std::vector<int> out(a.size());
    int scaler = pm(a.size(), modulus - 2, modulus);
    for (int k = 0; k < a.size() / 2; ++k) {
        int p = even_ntt[k];
        int q = (omegas[k] * odd_ntt[k]) % modulus;
        out[k] = ((p + q)*scaler) % modulus;
        out[k + a.size() / 2] = (((p - q + modulus))*scaler) % modulus;
    }

    return out;
}
vector<int> ntt_mul_nwc_attempt(vector<int>p, vector<int>q, int gen=GEN, int modulus=MODULUS){
 int deg_d = p.size();
 vector<int>pp=p;
 vector<int>qq=q;
 for(int i=0;i<deg_d;i++){pp.push_back(0);qq.push_back(0);}
 vector<int>pp_ntt=cooley_tukey_ntt(pp);
 vector<int>qq_ntt=cooley_tukey_ntt(qq);
 vector<int>rr_ntt;
 for(int i=0;i<pp.size();i++)
 {
    rr_ntt[i]=((pp_ntt[i]*qq_ntt[i])%modulus);
 }
 vector<int>rr=cooley_tukey_intt(rr_ntt);
 
 for(int i=deg_d;i<rr.size();i++)
 {
    rr[i - deg_d] = (rr[i - deg_d] - rr[i]) % modulus;
    rr[i] = 0;
 }
 rr.resize(deg_d);
 return rr;
}
int main() {
    vector<int>p = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    vector<int>q = {1, 3, 5, 7};
    vector<int>pq_nwc_attempt = ntt_mul_nwc_attempt(p, q);
    for(auto i:pq_nwc_attempt)cout<<i<<" ";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please do not SHOUT. I tried, but my eyes refuse to read this.

Comment: `a[i + 1]` is out of bounds when `i == a.size()-1` (which happens when `a.size()` is odd)

Comment: `pp`,`qq`, `rr`,`q`, `p`. Single / 2-letter variable names are confusing and hide bugs.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/PM3G389h6

Comment: bad_alloc usually means you asked for Zounds... storage. Considering how much virtual addressing space is available on a modern computer, often this results from a program that allocates a truly ridiculous container, leaks like a sieve, or asks for a negative size (which did a two's compliment roll-around to an astronomically large number). This should be easy fodder for a debugger to isolate for you.

Comment: Tactical note: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` loads a lot of bullets into the gun by including the entire C++ Standard Library. [Don't do this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/4581301). `using namespace std;` takes the safety off by making everything in the Standard Library accessible in the global namespace where it can collide with the identifiers in your code. This makes it really easy to shoot your foot off, so [don't do it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/4581301).

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely wrong:

```
std::vector<int>rr_ntt;
for (int i = 0; i < pp.size(); i++)
{
    rr_ntt[i] = ((pp_ntt[i] * qq_ntt[i]) % modulus);
}
```

The `rr_ntt` vector is empty.  Any attempt of accessing index `i` of the `rr_ntt` vector in the `for` loop is an out-of-bounds access.

If you had used `at()` instead of `[]` to access the elements, the error is easily seen with [this example](https://godbolt.org/z/qMoq1Mv65), as a `std::out_of_range` exception is thrown.

Whether this is the exact cause of the problem you're seeing, I don't know.  But I do know that your program has an out-of-bounds access, meaning that the behavior of the code from there is undefined.